# Why am I getting an ImportError when I try to run Pyramid?

Tags: python, linux, pylons, pyramid

I'm trying to go through the "[Single File Tasks](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/single_file_tasks/single_file_tasks.html)" tutorial from the Pyramid documentation, but I'm running into a problem with actually running the single-file project.

I am running Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 11.10. I've installed setuptools, installed virtualenv, and created a virtualenv in my home directory with the following command:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages env
```

I then installed Pyramid from within the `env` directory created above using the following command:

```
bin/easy_install pyramid
```

Continuing to follow the Single File Tasks tutorial's directions, I created a Pyramid project inside my `env` directory.

The problem starts at this point: when I run `python tasks.py`, it responds with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tasks.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyramid.config import Configurator
ImportError: No module named pyramid.config
```

I am really interested in using Pyramid but I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

run the app from your python env,

```
../bin/python tasks.py
```

assuming your in env/tasks

Comment: Deactivating and activating again the environment when installing new executables picks the right path when installing new executables in the environment.

Comment: I am having the same problem. But for me its now giving me "ImportError: No module named pyramid_mako
" not found