# Failed to import Mako template

Tags: python, unix, python-2.7, pyramid, mako

I am learning Pyramid and following the [Tasks](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/single_file_tasks/single_file_tasks.html#single-file-tutorial) tutorial. When I run the tasks.py, I am getting the following error **"ImportError: No module named 'pyramid_mako'"**

I have my pyramid installed in the following location also the virtual environment in **Users/my_name/env/bin/python**  also there is pyton2.7 in **usr/local/lib/bin/python**

I installed the Mako template using pip install Mako and it get installed in the **usr/local/lib/bin/python2.7/site-packages**.

Now I am not sure from where and how to run the tasks.py. I tried running it usr/local/lib/bin/python and it gives me error that "ImportError: No module named pyramid.config
" because my python environment is in /Users/my_name/env/bin/ (Ref: [Why am I getting an ImportError when I try to run Pyramid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863418/why-am-i-getting-an-importerror-when-i-try-to-run-pyramid))

it keeps looking for Mako template in **/Users/my_name/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages** And i also moved the Mako folders to that location from **usr/local/lib/bin/python2.7/site-packages** still it wasn't working.

Can you guys help me how to install Mako template on the python environment and run that application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install Mako template on virtual environment and run that application

```
Users/my_name/env/bin/easy_install pyramid_mako
Users/my_name/env/bin/python tasks.py
```

you should try virtualenvwrapper

```
easy_install virtualenvwrapper
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
mkvirtualenv [env1]
workon [env]
deactivate
```